# What type to use for a `constexpr` map?

Tags: c++, c++17, constexpr, stdmap

**Ideally** I would like to write:

```
constexpr std:map<std::string, std::string> my_map = 
  {{"key1", "val1"}, {"key2", "val2"}, };
```

*or*

```
constexpr std:unordered_map<std::string, std::string> my_map =
  {{"key1", "val1"}, {"key2", "val2"}, };
```

But neither is possible (at least not in current language [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17))

So what is the alternative ?

For example, what I ***can*** do is the following:

```
constexpr std::initializer_list< std::pair<const char*, const char *> > my_map = 
  {{"key1", "val1"}, {"key2", "val2"}, };
```

and then construct a `std::map` when needed *at runtime*. I know I could also use `inline` instead of `constexpr`, but then I would be unable to use at compile time (perhaps at a later stage in development). But, it is somewhat unsatisfactory (since I had to runtime construct the map just for the lookup) and I'm wondering: is there a better solution ?

Comment: you can try frozen https://github.com/serge-sans-paille/frozen

Comment: If your keys are sorted, you can store them in a C-style array (or `std::array`) then use `std::binary_search` on them.

Comment: @BobBills for this particular use case - I probably would have go with the current solution I have - but for other users coming here, that is a great answer !

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm nice suggestion, but unfortunately they aren't sorted

Comment: ...but you could sort them. If you do not add or remove elements then a `std::map` wont give you much that a sorted array cannot do

Comment: @darune: Why do you need it to be `constexpr` specifically?

Comment: @NicolBolas I can get away with a runtime solution - but it will not be able to check at compile that keys are present - this is intended for a DocString type of system for member variables (not directly translateable to c++).

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm if there exist some constexpr function that just return the strings in a sorted array, that would be brilliant !